# Retrofit: Json with 2 dynamic fields(one field in the other) into Gson

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2

Using retrofit I need to call an Api which gives me a json with dynamic fields which change depending on the parameters that i give.For example,for 'symbol' parameters "ETH","XRP" and 'convert' parameter "USD" the response will be the following Json:

```
{
   "data":{
      "ETH":{
         "id":1027,
         "name":"Ethereum",
         "symbol":"ETH",
         "quote":{
            "USD":{
               "price":225.911630584,
               "volume_24h":9744372948.14671,
               "percent_change_1h":-2.87302,
               "percent_change_24h":-4.94698,
               "percent_change_7d":-26.9517,
               "market_cap":24152563209.793915
            }
         }
      },
      "XRP":{
         "id":52,
         "name":"XRP",
         "symbol":"XRP",
         "quote":{
            "USD":{
               "price":0.31390356279,
               "volume_24h":1610830847.99846,
               "percent_change_1h":-1.37633,
               "percent_change_24h":-0.0736244,
               "percent_change_7d":-21.4656,
               "market_cap":13361806194.547878
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I've created ApiClass as follows:

```
public class ApiConstants {
    public static String APP_KEY="xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx";
    public static String BASE_URL = "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/";
    public static final String CRYPTOCURRENCYQUOTES="v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest";
```

I have this interface:

```
public interface CoinToCoin {
    @GET(ApiConstants.CRYPTOCURRENCYINFO)
    Call<MainClass...base class that must be created> convertCoinToCoin(@Header("X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY") String appkey,                                                
               @Query("symbol") String 
coinToCoinConvertedCoinSymbol, @Query("convert") String 
coinToCoinSymbol);
}
```

My retrofit:

```
    public class RetrofitClient {
        private static RetrofitClient instance = null;
        private Retrofit retrofit;
        private OkHttpClient client;
        private CoinToCoin coinToCoin;

    private RetrofitClient() {

        OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        client = okHttpBuilder.build();
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(ApiConstants.BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();

        coinToCoin= retrofit.create(CoinToCoin.class);
    }

    public static RetrofitClient getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new RetrofitClient();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public CoinToCoin getCoinToCoin() { return coinToCoin; 
}

}
```

In my main activity i'll have to instantiate my RetrofitClient

```
private RetrofitClient retrofit;
retrofit = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
```

and then make a call to retrieve the data i need:

```
    Call<MainClass...this must be created> call =retrofit.getCoinToCoin().convertCoinToCoin(ApiConstants.CRYPTOCURRENCYINFO,"ETH,XRP","USD");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<MainClass...this must be created>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MainClass...this must be created> 
call, Response<MainClass...this must be created> response) {

           }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MainClass...this must be created> 
call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

From what i found out the best way to do this is with HashMaps and deserialiazation  but i have no ideea how.
Also i don't really know how the classes that i need to create should look.

Please be explicit and tell me how to do it step by step..im a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd go for a map like you said. Based on your json you can define an object for each coin:

```
public class Quote {      
  @SerializedName("price")
  private double price;
  @SerializedName("volume_24h")
  private double volume24h;
  @SerializedName("percent_change_1h")
  private double percentChange1h;
  @SerializedName("percent_change_24h")
  private double percentChange24h;
  @SerializedName("percent_change_7d")
  private double percentChange7d;
  @SerializedName("market_cap")
  private double marketCap;
  // getters and setters
}

public class Coin {
  @SerializedName("id")
  private int id;
  @SerializedName("name")
  private String name;
  @SerializedName("symbol")
  private String symbol;
  @SerializedName("quote")
  private Map<String, Quote> quote;
  // getters and setters
}
```

I'm not sure if the data is always the same, but if not you can follow a similar approach:

```
public class CoinResponse {
  @SerializedName("data")
  private Map<String, Coin> data;
  // getters and setters
}
```

Now you can use `CoinResponse` as the response for your retrofit interface.

Comment: The "data" field is always the same.The only fields that change are  "ETH","XRP","USD" from the example that i gave.

Comment: Ok, then my solution should hold